# How do I pass multiple parameters in sql cursor

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
declare @USERID varchar(50)
Declare @FileName Varchar(500)
declare @file_ext nvarchar(30)
Declare @exeVariable nvarchar(4000)
declare @file_type nvarchar(50)
declare @messageBody nvarchar(MAX)
declare @attach nvarchar(MAX)
declare @p_recipients varchar(MAX)
declare @EMAIL_ID  varchar(MAX)
declare @count float
set @file_type='PDF'
SET @file_ext='.pdf'

begin



Declare @USERID_Cursor Cursor
Set @USERID_Cursor = Cursor for 
SELECT DISTINCT empcode,email FROM EmailTable

Open @USERID_Cursor
Fetch NEXT from @USERID_Cursor into @USERID,@EMAIL_ID

While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
SET @exeVariable = '[FilePath=C:\inetpub\wwwroot\WebServer\ProgramGuide\Report1.Stat]'
SET @exeVariable = @exeVariable +'[ConnStr=Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=*abcdef;Persist          Security Info=True;User ID=abcd;Initial Catalog=OneKeyAgile;DataSource= ]'
SET @exeVariable = @exeVariable + '[NC_CountS=1][NC_ParaS=mcode][mcode='+@USERID+']     [NC_CountN=0][NC_ParaN=][NC_CountD=0][NC_ParaD=]'                                  
SET @exeVariable = @exeVariable + '[FormatTyp=PDF][ExportPath=F:\abcd\Report 1-'+@USERID+'.PDF] [StatWebServer=http://192.168.5.25/WebServer/Service.asmx]'
SET @exevariable = '"C:\"Program Files"\"ABCD"\Reporter.exe ' + @exevariable  +'"'

PRINT @exevariable
exec xp_cmdshell @exeVariable


SET @p_recipients = @EMAIL_ID
SET @attach = 'F:\BUDGET\Report1' + @USERID + @file_ext+''
SET @messageBody = ' '

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'ABCD', 
@recipients = @p_recipients,
@body = @messageBody,
@file_attachments = @attach
Fetch NEXT from @USERID_Cursor into @USERID,@EMAIL_ID
END
Close @USERID_Cursor
Deallocate @USERID_Cursor


end
```

Ok, this is my cursor. I use this to pass empcode from the email_table to the cursor which then passes this parameter into my reporting tool. This works fine.

Let's say, I want to now include another variable from email_table,bcode,which also needs to be passed into the cursor. Any help?

Comment: Oops, sorry about that. What about now?

Comment: Aha, after several iterations we begin to arrive at the real issue. I suspect what you are trying to ask us is: "how do I include a non-distinct column in a distinct query" Am I right?

Comment: Well, let me put it this way. I need to send reports to my sales team based on their employee id, which is the parameter being passed in the cursor above. We now want to be able to filter people by not just their employee id but also their branch, which is the second parameter I want to pass. So now based on these two parameters, the reports get filtered to the right people at the right branch.